# There is no measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ that is invariant to translations and fullfills $\mu([0,1])=1$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Show that no measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ exists which is invariant to translations and which fullfills $\mu([0,1])=1$.
> >     **Hint**: First, show that $x\sim y: \Leftrightarrow x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$ defines an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$. Then suggest the existence of a set $H\subset (0,1]$ which contains exactly one representative of $(0,1]$ of each equivalence class. Then check the properties of a measure by using the union $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1]}(H+q)$.

Hello! First of all I give you the definition of translation invariance:

---

A set function $m$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{S})$ for a $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is called invariant to translations if for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $A\in\mathcal{S}$ it is $m(A)=m(A+x)$, whereat $A+x:=\left\{y+x: y\in A\right\}$.

---

Then could you please help me to follow the given hint? Because I do not understand the hint.

The first thing is to show the equivalence relation. I think I can handle this:

1) Consider $x\in [0,1]$. Then $x\sim x$, because $x-x=0\in\mathbb{Q}$.

2) Consider $x,y\in [0,1]$ with $x\sim y$. That means $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Because $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is an Abelian group and $y-x$ is the inverse element of $x-y$, it follows that $y-x\in\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $y\sim x$.

3) Consider $x,y,z\in M$ with $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$, i.e. $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}, y-z\in\mathbb{Q}$. Because $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ is an Abelian group, the sum of both, i.e. $(x-y)+(y-z)=x-z\in\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $x\sim z$.

Now what's about that set $H$? I did not understand this.

Your sincerly

math12

Comment: You get a contradiction about $\mu(H)$. Taking measures on both sides of the equality $\cup_{q}(H+q)=$<fill the blank>, what do you get ?

Comment: Show that $[0,1] \subseteq \cup_{q}(H+q)$. Deduce that $\mu(\cup_{q}(H+q)) \geq 1$.

Comment: But what is that set $H$ resp. how can I find it/ say that it exists?

Comment: $H$ is a set of representatives: You consider all equivalence classes (which are a collection of pairwise disjoint sets) and pick one arbitrary element from each class. Admittedly, you cannot write down such a set explicitly and there's a lot of chosing going on - more than some would accept feasible. ;)

Comment: Perhaps someone can comment on the extent to which one could relax AC and still find a suitable $H$. Math12: may I suggest also tagging the question [axiom-of-choice]?

Comment: So, what I get is that $[0,1]\subset\biguplus_{q}(H+q)\subset [-1,2]$. Mononoty: $\mu([0,1])\leq\mu(\biguplus_{q}(H+q))\leq\mu([-1,2])$. Why is that a contradiction?

Comment: I guess it follows $1\leq\sum_{q}\mu(H+q)\geq 1$, so $\sum_{q}\mu(H+q)=1$. Assuming, that $\mu$ is invariant to translations it follows $\mu(H+q)=\mu(H)$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [-1,1]$. That are infinite many ones and so the sum can only be 0 or $\infty$. Contradiction!

Comment: Why does one chose representative of the equivalence classes out of $(0,1]$ and not out of whole $[0,1]$?

Comment: Isn't $\mu([-1,2])=3$, because $[-1,2]=[-1,0]\cup [0,1]\cup [1,2]$ and assuming that $\mu$ is invariant to translations and $\mu([0,1])=1$, it follows $\mu([-1,0])=\mu([1,2])=1$ because these intervalls are only translations?

Comment: @math12, $0\sim 1$, so it doesn't really matter. And yes, $\mu([-1,2])=3$.